# Load excel files with different columns from a directory into database using SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have 40 excel sheets in a single folder. I want to load them all in different tables sql server database through SSIS package. The difficulty I am having is because of different number and name of columns in each excel sheet.
Can this task be achievable through a single package?

Comment: Yes. A single package with one excel data source per sheet format. If you have seven different formats then you need seven Excel sources with the source format defined in them. (they might all sit in one data flow or they might sit in seperate data flows). Have you imported one sheet yet?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if you want to do it in one data flow, you can write custom C# source component with multiple outputs. In the script task you'll figure out the file type and send the data to the proper output.
NPOI library(https://npoi.codeplex.com/) is a good way to read excel files in C#.

But if you have fixed file formats I would prefer to create N Data Flows inside Foreach loop container. Use regular Excel source components and just ignore errors in each data flow. This will let you get a file and try to load it in each data flow one by one. On error you will not fail the package but just go to the next data flow until you find the proper file format.

Answer (score 0):

It can only be done, by adding multiple sources or using a script component, white a flag on what sheet it is. Then you can use a conditional split and enter multiple destinations.